# Acceptable way to document the return value for an ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, documentation

I have the following action method in a controller:

```
/// <summary>
/// Redirects the user to the Dashboard for their default role.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>???</returns>
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = ((User)User).Roles[0].Name });
}
```

What is a common or acceptable way to document the return value for a controller action that performs a redirect (or a similar operation)?

Comment: Good question! I think that the comments have to be human-readable. I always try to start the returns comments in MVC controllers actions with:  "An MVC view representing..." , "A redirect action to...", "An empty response", "A JSON representation of...". But I don't know whether this is best practice or not.

Comment: just remove 'return' section :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I opened up a .NET Framework DLL in Object Browser and looked at the method signature.  If that method returned some value, usually the `<returns>` XML comment wass filled out.  Feel free to use that as a guideline.

If you have to deal with a really strict code analysis or StyleCop dictator, I suggest the following:

```
/// <returns>Returns a redirect to an action.</returns>
```

Otherwise, the norm seems to be to drop the word 'Returns' and go with something like:

```
/// <returns>A redirect to an action.</returns>
```

In either case, the text within the returns tag is typically a verbatim string of the object type returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ProducesResponseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute) attributes. Though, it's `.NET Core` only, but it's 2020, e.g.

```cs
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect)]
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = ((User)User).Roles[0].Name });
}
```

A more comprehensive way of adding this attribute would be

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FooDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public Task<IActionResult> GetFoo()
{
  // ...
}
```

And since ASP.NET Core 2.1 we have [ActionResult<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types), so the happy path can be less verbose in the attributes and also gets a type check at the compilation stage.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public Task<ActionResult<FooDto>> GetFoo()
{
  // ...
}
```